# mySQL query optimization for zip arrays

Tags: mysql, arrays, select, for-loop

All,
I'm looking up a zip code and then finding all the other zip codes in a given radius. I'm trying to make a single call to the database so what kind of query should I use? I was thinking about using an OR clause but was wondering if anyone had any better ideas on query optimization for this? I thought about doing something like this but any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

```
$zipArray = $zipLoc->inradius($_SESSION['pav_event_zip_code'],50);
$total_zips = count($zipArray);
$sql = "Select * from vendor where vendor_zip='$zipArray[0]'";
for($i=1;$i<$total_zips;$i++){
    $sql. = "OR vendor_zip='$zipArray[$i]'";
}
```

Comment: What is $zipLoc->inradius() ?

Comment: I have an include that is a class that is looking up all of the zip codes in that radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IN statement, although it won't be faster it's definitly easier to read:

```
$zipArray = $zipLoc->inradius($_SESSION['pav_event_zip_code'],50);
$zipArray[] = -1; // make sure the IN Statement does not fail
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM vendor WHERE vendor_zip IN ('.implode(',',$zipArray).')';
```

Make sure you have the column vendor_zip indexed